# ListBox select all loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, listbox

Working with this code, throwing index out of range error, suggestions? Added the entire code. While the listbox items are all selected only the last one is input into the database. I suspect it has something to do with the Affected as Integer and the Affected call at the end of the code.

```
Dim Affected As Integer = 0

    Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
        {
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
            .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "CalcDB.accdb"),
            .PersistSecurityInfo = False
        }



    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
        Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
            cmd.CommandText =
                <SQL>
                INSERT INTO CalcOps 
                (
                    NumOne, 
                    Operation, 
                    NumTwo,
                    Equal,
                    Result
                ) 
                VALUES 
                (
                    @NumOne, 
                    @Operation, 
                    @NumTwo, 
                    @Equal,
                    @Result
                )
            </SQL>.Value

            With cmd.Parameters

                .AddWithValue("@NumOne", NumOne.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@Operation", ListBox1.Tag)
                .AddWithValue("@NumTwo", NumTwo.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@Equal", "=")
                .AddWithValue("@Result", Result.Text)

            End With

            Dim x As Integer

            For x = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
                If ListBox1.GetSelected(x) = False Then
                    ListBox1.SetSelected(x, True)
                End If
            Next


            Try
                cn.Open()
                Affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Problem:" & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message)
            End Try

        End Using
    End Using

    If Affected = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert done")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Insert failed")
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Why you are looping empty? I mean this line of code `For x = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

    Next`

Comment: The list box will have 1 to 10 entries, I need to select them all to move to a db

Comment: I updated the original to show all of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the If statement inside the loop. The `x` loop variable only increments or decrements, depending on `Step`, inside the loop.

```
For x As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
  If ListBox1.GetSelected(x) = False Then
    ListBox1.SetSelected(x, True)
  End If
Next
```

Comment: One and done, thanks, figured it was some stupid I was missing.